# Iron-ajax 401 unauthorized or CORS issue

Tags: cors, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x, iron-ajax

I'm having issues using iron-ajax on Polymer 2.0. My code's based on a Polymer 1.0 one and I'm trying to adapt it. I send my form through a POST like this:

Template:

```
        <div class="wrapper-btns">
            <paper-button raised class="primary" on-tap="postLogin">Log In</paper-button>
            <paper-button class="link" on-tap="postRegister">Sign Up</paper-button>
        </div>
```

Code:

```
    _setReqBody() {
        this.$.registerLoginAjax.body = this.formData;
    }

    postLogin() {
        this.$.registerLoginAjax.url = 'http://localhost:3001/sessions/create';
        this._setReqBody();
        this.$.registerLoginAjax.generateRequest();
    }
```

Iron-Ajax setup:

```
    <iron-localstorage name="user-storage" value="{{storedUser}}"></iron-localstorage>
    <app-data key="userData" data="{{storedUser}}"></app-data>

    <iron-ajax
        id="registerLoginAjax"
        method="post"
        content-type="application/json"
        handle-as="text"
        on-response="handleUserResponse"
        on-error="handleUserError"></iron-ajax>
```

And when I do I get the following error:

> POST http://localhost:3001/sessions/create 400 (Bad Request)

And when I use this line on the Iron-Ajax :

```
with-credentials="true"
```

The error as it seems is a CORS problem:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3001/sessions/create.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you have on server side? Is it worked correct with Polymer 1.*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the server-side code for the `http://localhost:3001/sessions/create` backend to send the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081/` in responses for requests from `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`, rather than sending back the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as it’s doing now.

The [*Credentialed requests and wildcards* section of the MDN page on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Credentialed_requests_and_wildcards) explains why:

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard.